# Accessing variable from another class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4

I'm trying to use a variable from one class in another, but I get the error, "run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'MyWindowClass'"

```
class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):
    updateProgressSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def run(self, MyWindowClass):
        for i in range(101):
           self.updateProgressSignal.emit(i)
           print ( MyWindowClass.pbTimeUpdate )
           time.sleep(MyWindowClass.pbTimeUpdate) 

class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QDialog ):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyWindowClass, self).__init__(*args)  
        self.pbTimeUpdate = .2
        self.myLongTask = TaskThread()
        self.myLongTask.updateProgressSignal.connect (self.onProgress)
        self.myLongTask.start()

    def onProgress (self, val )
        print (val)
```

I've tried making the variable global (declared outside both classes in same file), but updating the variable value in in one class, the other class still sees the original value)

What could be the issue?

Comment: You're calling `TaskThread.run` without arguments somewhere, but it expected to be called with 1 positional argument, e.g. *MyWindowClass*, which btw would shadow the global name referencing the class. As `MyWindowClass` according to your example is global, just leave the argument out of `def run(self, MyWindowClass):`.

Comment: Please share the entire stack trace/error message, and the code that is referring to. We need to see the failed call to `run()`

Comment: Not sure if it's the same thing, but I don't call run, I call start...    I create the task and start this way:  self.myLongTask = TaskThread()  self.myLongTask.updateProgressSignal.connect (self.onProgress), self.myLongTask.start() ..  This portion works, the TaskThread does start running at this point.     I tried just def run(self) but get an error that MyWindowClass doesn't have the pbTimeUpdate attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
class MyWindowClass(QtGui.QDialog):
    pbTimeUpdate = .2

class TaskThread(QtCore.QThread):
    updateProgressSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def run(self):
        for i in range(101):
           self.updateProgressSignal.emit(i)
           print(MyWindowClass.pbTimeUpdate)
           time.sleep(MyWindowClass.pbTimeUpdate)
```

Comment: In this order, and with just the run(self), the error changes to:  AttributeError: type object 'MyWindowClass' has no attribute 'pbTimeUpdate'.     It's clearly there, why doesn't it recognize it?

Comment: yeah because you need and instance of MyWindowClass, as this attribute is set in __init__ not as a class level attribute

Comment: Thanks! that did the trick..   in the MyWindowClass I just had to make sure that I whenever I wanted to change the variable, I had to do it like MyWindowClass.pbTimeUpdate = .5' instead of pbTimeUpdate = .5 or self.pbTimeUpdate = .5